# is there a way to overlay an image onto an object in three.js?

Tags: javascript, deployment, three.js

I am attempting to overlay an image onto an object in three.js

i have an interior and exterior sphere objects, rotating in either direction; the idea is to overlay several images onto the exterior sphere. overlay as to take on the shape of the sphere.

```
<body>
        <!-- <script href="engine.js" type="text/javascript"/> -->
        <script type="module">
            
            import * as THREE from 'https://unpkg.com/three/build/three.module.js';

            const scene = new THREE.Scene();
            const camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 75, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0.1, 1000 );

            const renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
            renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
            document.body.appendChild( renderer.domElement );
            

            /* GEOMETRY */
            const torusOne = new THREE.TorusGeometry( 5, 3, 20, 75 );
            const torusTwo = new THREE.TorusGeometry( 5.1, 3.1, 20, 25 );
            

            /* BUILDS */
            let wireFrameOne = new THREE.WireframeGeometry(torusOne);
            let lineOne = new THREE.LineSegments(wireFrameOne);
            lineOne.material.color.setHex(0xffffff); //(0xff9f80)
            scene.add(lineOne);
            
            let wireFrameTwo = new THREE.WireframeGeometry(torusTwo);
            let lineTwo = new THREE.LineSegments(wireFrameTwo);
            lineTwo.material.color.setHex(0x99ff80);
            scene.add(lineTwo);

                        /* ^^^^^^^ add image overlay(s) to wifreFrameTwo ^^^^^^^ */ 
            

            /* LIGHT_CAMERA */
            const color = 0xFFFFFF;
            const intensity = 5;
            const light = new THREE.DirectionalLight(color, intensity);
            light.position.set(19, 5,10);
            scene.add(light);

            camera.position.z = 15;

        
            lineOne.rotation.x = 90;
            lineTwo.rotation.x = 90;


            /* ANIMATE FUNCTION */
            function animate() {
                requestAnimationFrame( animate );

                lineOne.rotation.z += 0.0007;
                lineTwo.rotation.z -= 0.003;
                
                renderer.render( scene, camera );
            }

            animate();
        </script>
    </body>
```

added line 4,5,&6. resulted in breaking the script. i haven't found much documentation on object overlays. is this something that is handled thru three.js or base javascript? any help is much appreciated!

```
                        let wireFrameTwo = new THREE.WireframeGeometry(torusTwo);
            let lineTwo = new THREE.LineSegments(wireFrameTwo);
            lineTwo.material.color.setHex(0x99ff80);
                        var x = document.createElement("IMG");
                        x.setAttribute("src", "pic1.jpg");
                        wireFreameTwo.attach(x);
            scene.add(lineTwo);
```